# Angular directive through innerHTML in typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead.js

I'm trying to use a custom template with typeahead.js by passing in an angular directive to the templates option.

```
$('.typeahead#players').typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 0
    }, {
      source: substringMatcher(typeaheadPlayers, 'player'),
      templates: {
        suggestion: function(data){
          return ['<div><avatar user-id="' + data.user_id + '" user-full-name="' + data.long_display_name + '" changed-src=' + true + '></avatar>',
                  '<p>' + data.long_display_name + '</p>',
                  '</div>'].join('\n');
        },
        empty: '<div><p>No users were found by that name.</p></div>'
      }
    });
```

The HTML gets injected properly and the `long_display_name` is displayed just fine. The directive that I've defined called `avatar` isn't firing at all. I've tried to `$compile` and I've tried passing in `ng-transclude`, but my directive still won't fire.

How can I pass in an angular directive into this template and trigger it to fire?

Comment: You sure you wanted to approve that edit on your post? It makes it a lot harder to read.

Comment: It is `$compile` that does the trick (they wouldn't call it like that for nothing). Working example of what you're trying to do won't hurt.

Comment: @estus i think you're correct that `$compile` is what I need. Where does that actually go? I re-factored to try to pass in `$compile(html)` where the `return` is, but got an `uncaught hierarchyrequesterror`. Most examples of `$compile` show it being placed within the actual directive, which isn't what I need in this case.

Comment: It is impossible to give you a reasonable answer without seeing the context of posted code. But the proper usage for $compile is `$compile(html)(scope)`, where 'scope' is actual $scope or `{ }` - if you don't need data binding there.

Comment: Ok thank you, I've updated to include the entire block that this is being used in. This is using the typeahead.js library and the `templates` object in this callback allows you to pass in an html block to be returned as a custom template for the returned suggestions. I basically want to `$compile` this returned block, I guess. But it won't let me just wrap that in the `$compile`. So I'm unsure of how it works.